# Upgrade PostgreSQL database. What happens with functions?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I have a really old PostgreSQL version - 8.3 and we would like to upgrade it to 8.4. It shouldn't be hard but I am worrying what will happen when function written by my own was added in newer version. By example I wrote function `A(text)` and function with exactly the same name and parameter was added in PostgreSQL 8.4. What will happen? My function will get override, I'll get some conflict or my function will be the valid one and PostgreSQL won't add it's own?

Comment: Why are you "upgrading" from one unsupported version to another unsupported version. If you upgrade today you should upgrade to 10 or at least 9.6

Comment: Well, I get information that it is much easier to upgrade just to 8.4. Heard that upgrade from dinosaur 8.3 to 9.6 or 10 would cause problems. It is production database and all actions need to be extremely safe.

Comment: Well, if you need to be _safe_  do not use unsupported versions. You will **have** to upgrade to a supported version anyway at some point. And doing 8.3. -> 8.4 -> 9.6 -> 10 is much more trouble than doing 8.3 -> 10 directly. The biggest change is the removal of many (dangerous) implicit casts that occurred from 8.3 to 8.4 but you will have to cope with that as well. And you shouldn't base such an important tasks on things "you have heard". You **have** to test it anyway yourself. So you might as well start testing with a modern version right from the start

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what do you mean by 'removal of many implicit casts'. Do you mean casting for example `'12'::bigint` which can be illegal in 8.4 or 9.6?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if you could clarify a bit 'removal of many implicit casts' I would be really grateful.

Comment: I remembered wrong. Those changes I was thinking of already happened in 8.3. Specifically this one: "*Non-character data types are no longer automatically cast to TEXT*" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-8-3.html#id-1.11.6.197.4.4 - a lot of badly written queries broke because of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All built-in functions are stored in the schema `pg_catalog`. All functions you wrote yourself are stored in a different schema (typically `public`).

As the "primary key" to identify a function is the schema **and** the name, there is no clash between your functions and any built-in function.

Comment: okey, but what will happen when I use 'A(text)' function `pg_catalog.A(text)`? Does it mean that by default functions are called from `public` catalog? What happens when I call function without any prefix?

Comment: The order in which functions are searched is defined through the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).